$A =\{x\in\Bbb Q\mid 0≤x^2<2\}$. Is the closure of $A˚$ compact?

$A =\{x\in\Bbb Q\mid 0≤x^2<2\}$. Is the closure of $A˚$ compact?

I think that it is, because if I take the closure of the interior of A, I'm adding every limit point on A, for example sqrt(2), so the sub sequences will all converge within the set. If my argument is correct, its not valid if $0<x$ strictly right? because one would never achieve the value zero? Or having the closure of the set automatically adds it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sorry! The problem is as it follows:
let K⊆Q given by K={x∈Q:0<x^2 <2}. ¿Is the closure of the interior points of K  compact? My question is if by closing K, I get the set P ={x∈R:0≤x^2 ≤2}, because in that case it would be compact

Why would it be empty? Sorry I don't understand, wouldn't it contain every rational q such that q squared lives in (−√2,√2‾)?

As K is in Q I understand it refers to the interior in Q. So for every q squared that lives in the given range, the sphere of radius e and centered in q is contained in K, isn't it? So the interior is not empty?

Ok I understand now and I agree. Maybe you should make this explicit in your post. But if you are considering everything in $\Bbb Q$ (interior and, logically, also closure), you cannot add $\sqrt2$ when taking the closure.

Cool, so it doesn't fill up the gaps when taking the closure. Thanks a lot!

Not compact though.  Take the open cover ${K_n: K_n = {x|x^2 < 2-\frac 1n}$.  No finite subcover.

Your observations if your metric space is $\mathbb Q$ rather than $\mathbb R$ are valid and so $A^\circ = A\setminus {0}$ rather than $\emptyset$ as it would be if your metric space were $\mathbb R$.  But are you certain the problem is not for the metric space being $\mathbb R$?  I strongly suspect it is as that's more common in introductory texts.

@fleablood Why $\setminus{0}$?

@fleablood  I doubt the metric space was supposed to be $\Bbb R$, because the question would then be trivial and strangely worded since, as we noticed, the interior would be empty hence also its closure.

@AnneBauval perhaps.  But I'd think if the metric is meant to be $\mathbb R$ then the point of the exercise is probably to illustrate the interior of the rationals is empty and that closure of an empty set is empty.  This is "trivial" but not the very first time a student sees it.  I don't know what they intent of the text was, but it'd by useful if a student could understand both. It's a matter of opinion but with the metric being assumed to by $\mathbb Q$, I'd argue it's still "trivial" and weirdly worded but that's just my opinion.

$A=(-\sqrt2,\sqrt2)\cap\Bbb Q=[-\sqrt2,\sqrt2]\cap\Bbb Q$ is both open and closed in $\Bbb Q$, so the closure of its interior is itself. This (metric) space is not compact, since it is not sequentially compact, i.e. it contains sequences with no converging subsequence. Alternatively, $A$ is not a compact as a subspace of $\Bbb Q$ because $\Bbb Q$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R$ and $A$ is not compact as a subspace of $\Bbb R$ (since it is not closed in $\Bbb R$).
As for $K:=\left((-\sqrt2,0)\cup(0,\sqrt2)\right)\cap\Bbb Q$, it is open in $\Bbb Q$ and its closure (in $\Bbb Q$) is $A$.
